# Updating JQuery to a newer version, but which one?

Tags: jquery

I'm fairly new to JQuery. I have a site that was built against jquery-1.2.6 and uses jquery-ui-personalized-1.6rc2.

What I would like to do is to upgrade JQuery and JQuery UI to use a more recent version. I thought that I'd be able to upgrade to the latest version but that breaks functionality in the site.

Can anyone tell me what version I can safely upgrade to without having to rewrite the entire app?

Comment: it all depends on what is broken and what needs fixed.

Comment: i *urge* you to rewrite your app.

Comment: One way or the other, you're going to have to re-write some of your app, its deprecated! Trying to find the solution that requires you NOT to re-write seems like a VERY bad idea...

Comment: You might be able to upgrade to 1.3.2 without having to rewrite the entire app, but the newer you go the more likely it is that you'll have to rewrite. The migrate plugin can only help so much.

Comment: @KevinB, thanks Kevin. I'll try and at least upgrade to 1.3.2. Can I also upgrade JQuery UI to a newer version as well?

Comment: You can upgrade it to the latest version that was compatible with 1.3.2

Comment: I'm not sure how to determine that. It's my understanding that when I download JQuery that if I want to use UI, I have to choose a version. I don't think they both come bundled, do they?

Comment: On the old api site there was always a version that was compatible with 1.3.2, then another that was 1.6+. The 1.3.2 version is no longer offered on the main site, but i believe it was version 1.7. You can download it from here along with one of the default themes. Good luck getting a custom theme though.: http://code.jquery.com/ui/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Download jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/)...

> The jQuery 1.x line had major changes as of jQuery 1.9.0. We strongly
>   recommend that you also use the jQuery Migrate plugin if you are
>   upgrading from pre-1.9 versions of jQuery or need to use plugins that
>   haven't yet been updated.

And later regarding jQuery Migrate...

> We have created the jQuery Migrate plugin to simplify the transition
>   from older versions of jQuery. The plugin restores deprecated features
>   and behaviors so that older code will still run properly on jQuery 1.9
>   and later. Use the uncompressed development version to diagnose
>   compatiblity issues, it will generate warnings on the console that you
>   can use to identify and fix problems. Use the compressed production
>   version to simply fix compatibility issues without generating console
>   warnings.

Alternatively you could try to track down a version of jQuery 1.8.x which shouldn't present compatibility issues, but it is only putting a bandaid on the problem.  Eventually you'll need to deal with 1.9.x or some version 2 variant.

Comment: So it appears that this is my best option. Thank you for grabbing that text for me, Yuck.

Answer (score 2):

You should upgrade your jQuery version and use **jQuery Migrate plugin** to keep old functionalities.

Read more at [jQuery download page](http://jquery.com/download/)

Comment: Note however the migrate plugin won't fix problems with migrating from 1.2.6-1.6.4, it only fixes 1.6.4-1.9+

Comment: OK. Thanks, Kevin. I think I'm going to leave it as it is for now. I'll look at maybe rewriting this in the coming weeks

Answer (score 1):

The latest version that follows the same code path as yours is 1.10.2, which still supports oldIE aka 6/7/8.  If you were to use jQuery 2.x then the oldest IE they support is IE9, and it might not be what you expect.  Also you'll need to get the latest jQuery UI too.

Comment: Thanks Travis. I've tried to use JQuery 1.10 I think but things break and unfortunately, I'm not very good with JQuery yet so a rewrite isn't an option for me at this point. If I'm understanding you correctly, you're saying that I should be able to use the latest JQuery and UI without breaking anything?

Comment: @NAN No, TravisO was saying that as of version 2.x, jQuery no longer supports IE 6, 7 or 8. Therefore, if any of your users might use those browsers then the *latest* version you should even consider is 1.10.2 -- although even that version may break some functionality on your site. User `Yuck` also notes that major changes were made in version 1.9.0, so try the versions just before that. I had to go back to ver 1.8.3 myself (latest version I could use before something broke).

Comment: 2.0.2 and 1.10.2 are THE SAME version of jQuery. 2.0.2 isn't newer, it's just a different branch of jQuery that drops support for oldIE. the 1.10.x and 2.x branches are being updated simultaneously for now.